# Where is the deprecated API at my class code ? I can't figure out

Tags: java, android-studio, colors, drawable, deprecated

It's a simple code, and the error message doesn't say where exactly is the deprecated usage.

[image]

```
package com.dev.marcellocamara.pgm.Helper;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

import com.dev.marcellocamara.pgm.R;

public class CardHelper {

    public static Drawable getBackground(Context context, int drawable){
        switch (drawable){
            case 1 : {
                return (context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.card_yellow));
            }
            case 2 : {
                return (context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.card_purple));
            }
            case 3 : {
                return (context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.card_green));
            }
            default : {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    public static Drawable getFlag(Context context, int flag) {
        switch (flag){
            case 1 : {
                return (context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.flag1));
            }
            case 2 : {
                return (context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.flag2));
            }
            case 3 : {
                return (context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.flag3));
            }
            default : {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    public static int getColor(Context context, int card) {
        switch (card){
            case 1 : {
                return (context.getResources().getColor(R.color.card1));
            }
            case 2 : {
                return (context.getResources().getColor(R.color.card2));
            }
            case 3 : {
                return (context.getResources().getColor(R.color.card3));
            }
            default : {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

As code says, I'm returning the drawable or the color. It's simple. Where is the warning that need a change, and how can I skip this warning, continue returning a drawable and a color ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Android API 22 `getResources().getDrawable()` was deprecated. Now you should use this method `getDrawable (int id, Resources.Theme theme)`

And `getColor (int id)` was deprecated in API 23. Now use `getColor(int, android.content.res.Resources.Theme)` instead.

Check this out for more info:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources

Comment: Didn't know that... Now I'm using `ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.color)`. Not sure how to use a theme yet with that `Resources.Theme`.

Comment: How to call **android.content.res.Resources.Theme** from Kotlin?